# Container localhost does not exist error when using Keras + Flask Blueprints

Tags: python, flask, keras

I am trying to serve a machine learning model via an API using Flask's Blueprints, here is my flask `__init__.py` file

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route("/healthcheck")
    def healthcheck() -> str:
        return "OK"

    # Registers the machine learning blueprint
    from . import ml
    app.register_blueprint(ml.bp)

    return app
```

The `ml.py`file which contains the blueprint for the `/ml` endpoint

```
import numpy as np
from . import configuration as cfg
import tensorflow as tf

from flask import (
    Blueprint, flash, request, url_for
)


bp = Blueprint("ml", __name__, url_prefix="/ml")
keras_model = None
graph = None

@bp.before_app_first_request
def load_model():
    print("Loading keras model")
    global keras_model
    global graph
    with open(cfg.config["model"]["path"], 'r') as model_file:
        yaml_model = model_file.read()
        keras_model = tf.keras.models.model_from_yaml(yaml_model)
        graph = tf.get_default_graph()
        keras_model.load_weights(cfg.config["model"]["weights"])

@bp.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict() -> str:
    global graph
    features = np.array([request.get_json()['features']])
    print(features, len(features), features.shape)
    with graph.as_default():
        prediction = keras_model.predict(features)
    print(prediction)
    return "%.2f" % prediction
```

I run the server using a command line script

```
#!/bin/bash 

export FLASK_APP=src
export FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

And if I go to `localhost:5000/healthcheck`I get the `OK` response as I should, when I run the following curl

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:5000/ml/predict \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
 "features" : [17.0, 0, 0, 12.0, 1, 0, 0]
}'
```

For the first time, I get the response `[[1.00]]`, if I run it again I get the following error

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: 
Error while reading resource variable dense/kernel from
Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. 
Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/dense/kernel)
         [[{{node dense/MatMul/ReadVariableOp}}]]
```

If I modify the Blueprint file the server will detect the changes and refresh it, I can call the API again and it will return the correct result for the first call and I am back to the error again. Why does this happen? And why only for the calls after the first one?

Comment: Does it survive if you directly run the relevant parts (so initialize things, and run the internals of `predict()` twice, with a hardcoded `features = np.array([[17.0,0,0,12.0,1,0,0]])`)?

Comment: No, I get the same error, I don't get the "run the internals of `predict()` though, it is a class function for the Keras model, I don't have access to it", still, I tried to run with the hardcoded value and it failed all the same

Comment: My question in other words: does it work without the web context? Practically if you make a copy of `ml.py`, remove `flask` references and annotations, put a hardcoded value into `features`, and run `load_model()` once, and `predict()` (with the hardcoded value) twice, would it work properly?

Comment: Yep, it does work, I am suspecting it has something to do with flask's "threading"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277280/preserving-global-state-in-a-flask-application might be interesting for you. Both `flask.g` and the remark on thread-safety. Unless the usage of your model is strictly read-only, you have to worry about possible simultaneous requests too.

Comment: Interesting, this seems to imply that I should load my model with every request (which I tested using @bp.before_app_request and it works), also, there is a comment in that answer that says that as of Flask 0.12 flask.g stores stuff in the application context rather than request context, is this the right way to do this then? Store my model in the app (or blueprint) context when the app is initialized?

Comment: As far as I understand, `.predict()` does not store/alter anything, thus a one-time initialization is enough, and `before_app_first_request` or `before_first_request` could be fine.

Comment: Initializing the model using before_app_first_request causes the same error as before, although initializing it every time with before_app_request works fine

Answer (score 2):

You can try creating a reference to the session that is used for loading the models and then to set it to be used by keras in each request. i.e. do the following:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.backend import set_session
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import load_model

tf_config = some_custom_config
sess = tf.Session(config=tf_config)
graph = tf.get_default_graph()

# IMPORTANT: models have to be loaded AFTER SETTING THE SESSION for keras! 
# Otherwise, their weights will be unavailable in the threads after the session there has been set
set_session(sess)
model = load_model(...)
```

and then in each request:

```
global sess
global graph
with graph.as_default():
    set_session(sess)
    model.predict(...)
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, rather I would say, creating session at the time of loading model and then predicting by loading the same session will always do the work in similar cases.

Comment: Nice, I will try it out ASAP, maybe configure a filter to load the session for every predict request?

Comment: Turns out it didn't work, I suspect it is because I am using flask blueprints... for now I am still loading the model before each requests

Comment: Please give some example of some_custom_config

Comment: @AbhilashRamteke If you don't want config, you can leave it like this,
sess = tf.Session()