# NotFoundError: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/embedding_1/embeddings)

Tags: tensorflow, embedding

I have a very simple code where i want to add embedding but i get error. I want to see the embedding output.

MY code:

```
input_question_ = Input((query_maxlen,))
embedded_question = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)(input_question_)

sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(embedded_question, feed_dict={ input_question_: queries_train})
```

Error :

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
> ~/miniconda2/envs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py
> ```
>
> in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
>          1364     try:
>       -> 1365       return fn(*args)
>          1366     except errors.OpError as e:
>
> ```
> ~/miniconda2/envs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py
> ```
>
> in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
>          1349       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(options, feed_dict, fetch_list,
>       -> 1350                                       target_list, run_metadata)
>          1351
>
> ```
> ~/miniconda2/envs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py
> ```
>
> in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list,
>   target_list, run_metadata)
>          1442                                             fetch_list, target_list,
>       -> 1443                                             run_metadata)
>          1444
>
> ```
> NotFoundError: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/embedding_1/embeddings)
>    [[{{node embedding_1/embedding_lookup}}]]
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-95-bf218d6ed295> in <module>
>      39 sess = tf.Session()
>      40 
> ---> 41 sess.run(embedded_question, feed_dict={ input_question_: queries_train})
>
> ~/miniconda2/envs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py
> ```
>
> in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
>           954     try:
>           955       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
>       --> 956                          run_metadata_ptr)
>           957       if run_metadata:
>           958         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)
>
> ```
> ~/miniconda2/envs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py
> ```
>
> in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
>          1178     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
>          1179       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
>       -> 1180                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
>          1181     else:
>          1182       results = []
>
> ```
> ~/miniconda2/envs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py
> ```
>
> in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options,
>   run_metadata)
>          1357     if handle is None:
>          1358       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
>       -> 1359                            run_metadata)
>          1360     else:
>          1361       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)
>
> ```
> ~/miniconda2/envs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py
> ```
>
> in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
>          1382                     '\nsession_config.graph_options.rewrite_options.'
>          1383                     'disable_meta_optimizer = True')
>       -> 1384       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
>          1385 
>          1386   def _extend_graph(self):
>
> ```
> NotFoundError: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/embedding_1/embeddings)
>    [[node embedding_1/embedding_lookup (defined at /home/mzaman/miniconda2/envs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748)
> ```
>
> ]]

Asking for a solution

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing a reference to the Tensorflow session the model is created with. Try:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

query_maxlen = 100
vocab_size = 500
embedding_dim = 32
input_question = tf.keras.layers.Input((query_maxlen,))
embedded_question = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)(input_question)

sess = tf.keras.backend.get_session()

output = sess.run(
    embedded_question, feed_dict={input_question: np.ones((1, query_maxlen))}
)
assert (1, 100, 32) == output.shape
print(output)
```

Related question:
[Container localhost does not exist error when using Keras + Flask Blueprints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54772549/container-localhost-does-not-exist-error-when-using-keras-flask-blueprints)