# can't initialize values before starting App in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm playing with Flask a little, for my application I would require a global storage which is updated by a Thread running in the background on the server. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277280/preserving-global-state-in-a-flask-application) question about global context and the answer from Johan Gov seems to work if I init the server using /create explicitly:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.json import jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

cache = {}

@app.route("/create")
def create():
    cache['foo'] = 0
    return jsonify(cache['foo'])

@app.route("/increment")
def increment():
    cache['foo'] = cache['foo'] + 1
    return jsonify(cache['foo'])

@app.route("/read")
def read():
    return jsonify(cache['foo'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

If I try to call the init automaticaly however, it fails as apparently no `cache["foo"]` is known.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.json import jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

cache = {}

def create():        #create does not have a route anymore
    cache['foo'] = 0

@app.route("/increment")
def increment():
    cache['foo'] = cache['foo'] + 1
    return jsonify(cache['foo'])

@app.route("/read")
def read():
    return jsonify(cache['foo'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create()    #initialize by default
    app.run()
```

Why is this happening? How can I initialize global state before starting the Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Cache as your app property, i always use this when i want to avoid awkward global definitions, just define the cache like this:

```py
# here u create a "cache" attribute for the app.
app.cache = {}
app.cache['foo'] = 0

# then after that when calling in a route:
# notice that we don't need the global keyword since we are using the app.
@app.route("/increment")
def increment():
    app.cache = app.cache + 1
    return jsonify(app.cache)
```

I even used relatively big objects like deep learning models using this method and had not problems at all.

Comment: thanks for your reply. The solution is right (works), thanks a lot. But there's a typo in it. All occurrences of app['cache'] should be app.cache imo. Maybe you can correct that and I can accept your answer

Comment: Actually what i meant was app.config['cache'], but still, the dot method (app.cache) seems a lot cleaner so i have changed it.

Answer (score 0):

tbh, the above code work for me without any change and I'm able to read and increment counter.

Try below code with `global` variable

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.json import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

cache = {}


def create():  # create does not have a route anymore
    global cache
    cache['foo'] = 0


@app.route("/increment")
def increment():
    global cache
    cache['foo'] = cache['foo'] + 1
    return jsonify(cache['foo'])


@app.route("/read")
def read():
    return jsonify(cache['foo'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create()  # initialize by default
    app.run()
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. unfortunately it won't work, no matter if with or without "global" keyword. However the above solution from KiLJ4deN works for me